# How to avoid and handle Neo.TransientError.Transaction.DeadlockDetected?

Tags: python, neo4j, deadlock

When doing load testing, I am seeing Deadlock errors happening occasionally, I added retries and its been working well. However, how do I know how to improve? The errors are quite vague so I cannot tell which query is causing this

> {code: Neo.TransientError.Transaction.DeadlockDetected} {message: ForsetiClient[transactionId=75637, clientId=2431] can't acquire ExclusiveLock{owner=ForsetiClient[transactionId=75634, clientId=2450]} on NODE_RELATIONSHIP_GROUP_DELETE(116) because holders of that lock are waiting for ForsetiClient[transactionId=75637, clientId=2431].

The weird thing is I dont think I have code that does a relationship delete. I am actually doing MERGE to add nodes and relationships along the lines of:

```
MERGE (o:Org {id: $orgId}) 
SET o.name=$name

MERGE (a:Item {id: $itemId})
SET a.orgId=$orgId,
    a.name=$itemName

MERGE (s:SubItem {id: $subItemId})
SET s.name=$subItemName

MERGE (o)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(a)
MERGE (a)-[:HAS_SUB_ITEM]->(s)
```

UPDATE:

Managed to identity the part causing the deadlock. I am modelling tags as a node and I suspect when many items use the same tag, and I try to merge the relationship, it causes a deadlock

```
MATCH (t:Tag {name: "a"})
MATCH (i:Item {name: "x"})
MERGE (i)-[:TAGGED]->(t)
```

I think this is the part causing deadlock often, how might I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason why deadlocks happen very frequently already. Also thanks to @Tomaž Bratanič's whose [link to the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/database-internals/locks-deadlocks/#deadlocks) helped. Specifically this part

> Lock taken on a node during the transaction creation phase to prevent deletion of that node and/or relationship group. This is different from the NODE lock in order to allow concurrent label and property changes together with relationship modifications.

And

> Table 2. Obtained locks for graph modifications
> Creating a relationship*
> If the node is sparse: NODE lock.
> If a node is dense: NODE DELETE prevention lock.

Important part is the part about dense node. Because I am modelling `:Category` as a node, 1 category can have many edges creating a "dense node".

Googling more about it, I found https://medium.com/neo4j/graph-modeling-all-about-super-nodes-d6ad7e11015b and started attempting to make the node less dense with some trade offs. Basically I made it a category specific to the "user" rather than globally. So instead of the category being uniqued by name, I also added a userId of sort so its a "composite key". I also added a TEXT index on name such that I can query easily for all category regardless of user quickly

Answer (score 0):

Deadlocks are usually not caused by a single query, but by queries that update the same node or relationship in parallel. To ensure valid data, Neo4j creates deadlocks on a node if it is being updated in a single transaction, so that two transactions cannot update the same node at the same time. It seems that the `delete` operation is an underlying operation that doesn't necessarily delete relationships. Check the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/database-internals/locks-deadlocks/#deadlocks) for more information.

Comment: Managed to identify the part causing the deadlock. Suspect its how I model "tags", since a tag can be assoiciated with many items and I frequently will tag many items with the same tag node, it probably increases the occurance of deadlocks. Is there any way I can avoid this? (Also updated my OP)

Comment: If you can somehow make sure that the same tag is not updated in parallel, that would help. Not sure how does your application look like and if that is possible.